# How the parameters of softmax are obtained in TensorFlow if the softmax is not included in training?

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

[Here is a tensorflow graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvjvR.png), as we can see that one of the inputs of cross entropy is the output of the logit layer, not the output of softmax in the graph.

I searched about it and found "WARNING: This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results." on [this webpage](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

My question is how the parameters of the softmax are obtained if this softmax is not trained?

Comment: In case the tensorflow graph can be opened, here is the webpage where i got the graph from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Softmax is a parameter free activation function like RELU, Tanh or Sigmoid: it doesn't need to be trained. It only computes the exponential of every logit and then normalize the output vector by the sum of the exponentials.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I just found.